# How to escape backslash in Java

Tags: java

I was trying to escape a Json string as an input via Scanner and print to console,
i was not able to escape " \ " by replacing it with " \\ ", 
I'm getting PatternSyntaxException
Here is my code

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = s.next();
        String s3 = "";
        if (str.contains("\\")) {
            s3 = str.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
            System.out.println(s3);
        }
```

Here is my input to scanner
{"name":"nokia"}\

Help me please !

Comment: Looks like a XY problem; if this is JSON why don't you use a JSON library?

Comment: This was closed long ago, but in case anyone's looking for it:
Given a string `s` that is a Windows-like path in which the backslashes *might or might not* have been escaped, you can insert additional backslashes *if necessary* with:
```s.replaceAll( "([^\\\\])(\\\\)([^\\\\])", "$1\\\\\\\\$3" )```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using regex you have to use 4 backslashes `\\\\` to parse the backslash as a literal.
So use `s3 = str.replaceAll("\\\\", someOtherString);`